# All of a sudden, I can no longer round the corners of shapes in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Suddently, every time I attempt to round the corners of a shape in illustrator, I get a message that says "This will apply another instance to this effect". When I select "Apply New Effect", nothing happens. I am confused because the word instance is ambiguous and not descriptive at all.

If someone could help me resolve this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the Appearance Panel.

Comment: It means you already have an instance of that effect applied to your shape. Is it possible the settings you used are so small you can't see them being applied? Regardless, go to Window > Appearance and look for "Rounded Rectangle" in the list. You can click on it to edit settings the effect applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify the corner radius on rounded rectangle in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/how-to-modify-the-corner-radius-on-rounded-rectangle-in-illustrator) Maybe you could simply do your rounded corners manually instead of using effects.

Answer (score 3):

Just like **Scott** mentioned in the comments, you should really look at your Appearance Panel. (If you can't find it in your sidebar go to the Window tab and look for Appearance like **Vicki** mentioned).

You should find the Rounded Rectangle there, click on it and "play" with the Shape Options.

This should be it.

[image]